# Date range calculating only 8737 hours in a year?

Tags: python, pandas, date, timestamp

I am using python [pandas date range](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.date_range.html) package to create a list of hourly timestamps for a calendar year. I code to do this, it looks like : 

`year = 2018
times = list(pd.date_range('{}-01-01'.format(year), '{}-12-31'.format(year), freq='H'))`

I expect the length of `times` to be 8760 (the number of hours in a year). But when I view the length of the `times` vector, it is only 8737. Why????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you specify a list by range, the first boundary is included and the second boundary is not.  So here you are including `{}-01-01` and not including `{}-12-31`.  But you are including the midnight value.

So, you need to include the last day of the year, but omit the "celebratory" New Year Hour:

```
>>> year = 2018
>>> times = list(pd.date_range('{}-01-01'.format(year), '{}-01-01'.format(year+1), freq='H'))
>>> times = times[:-1]
>>> len(times)
8760
```

You need to include the New Year's Day, `{}-01-01`, so that you get New Year's Eve, `{}-12-31`.  But then you get the midnight hour since that's what starts the day.  Hence the need to eliminate the last entry in the list: `times = times[:-1]`, so that you're ending at 11:00pm on 12-31.